# Creating IBM MQ queues from C# code

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Is is possable to create and delete queues using the amqdnet wrapper, or some other API from c# code?

I'ld like to be able to create some queues as part of an automated test suite if required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up imlementing this by starting a new process and running MQSC with si and so rederection, not as clean as I would have liked but it works.

Originaly I used the MO74 SupportPac that adds powershell access to MQ, This worked realy well and looked nice in code. However our target machines don't have powershell installed and I was unable to get it added as a pre-req for a minor feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that they're not available in the API within the amqmdnet.dll assembly. In which case you may have PINVOKE to the C api.

If it is then  [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pk_khuman/AquickstartCsharpWebsphereMQ07112006024017AM/AquickstartCsharpWebsphereMQ.aspx) example should get to close to the solution.

Comment: It's not included in the .net API, It is included in the MQ Powershell extentions. So I might investigate that.